# Possible uiloader issue when converting pyside app using cx_freeze

Tags: python, pyside, cx-freeze, uiloader

I am trying to convert a *pyside* app to an executable (.exe) on Windows using *cx_freeze*. The packaging works with no problem, but when starting the generated .exe file, I get the following error:

> ImportError: could not import module "PySide.QtXml"

When I try to convert the app shipped with *cx_Freeze\Samples\PyQt4*, it runs with no problems.

In this sample application there is just a simple `QDialog` called, but in my application I used *QtDesigner* for GUI design and I load it with *PySide* `UiLoader` directly in my py.file:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    loader = QUiLoader()
    self.ui = loader.load('xxxx.ui',self)
    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
```

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from PySide import QtXml

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': 'atexit'
    }
}

build_exe_options = {
    'includes': ['atexit'],
    }

executables = [
    Executable('xxx.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='xxx',
      version = '0.10',
      description = 'First try',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

In my opinion there's some problem using `UiLoader` when converting with *cx_freeze* but I have no clue how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old question. Still I am answering as it would help someone who is looking for a solution.

The solution is so simple that you just need to add "PySide.QtXml" to the includes list. After this your setup.py will look like this

```
build_exe_options = {
    'includes': ['atexit'],
    'packages': ['PySide.QtXml'],
    }
```